# what is the result of retrieving Server TimeStamp with an Offline Connection

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

what is the result of retrieving Server TimeStamp with an Offline Connection in Firebase?
null? (I'm guessing)

so using special locations at /.info/serverTimeOffset is always necessary for offline apps?

Comment: Are you specifically asking what happens if you write a server timestamp at a location while offline, then attempt to read it again while still offline?  Because once that value gets synchronized, it will always just be a number without any record of it having been a special server timestamp.

Comment: I'm ordering items in a recyclerview by the server timestamp. But it looks like the sorting is not working in offline connection. When I change to connected state it orders items well. So retrieving the timestamp without connection its just like nothing happpens, no results.  – Doug Stevenson

Answer (score 2):

I wrote this bit of code:

```
final DatabaseReference ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("foo");
ref.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        Log.d("TAG", "system time " + System.currentTimeMillis());
        Log.d("TAG", "snap " + dataSnapshot);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
    }
});
ref.setValue(ServerValue.TIMESTAMP);
new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        ref.setValue(ServerValue.TIMESTAMP);
    }
}, 2000);
```

When run offline, it will set a timestamp, then set another one two seconds later.  The listener will fire each time, and the value of the timestamp will match (or almost exactly match) the system time from System.currentTimeMillis().

Then, when the device goes online, the value will synchronize, and it will appear much more different from the local time (because the actual server time has finally kicked in).

Here's what the logs look like.  You can see the third pair of logs has the more-apparent timestamp difference after the online sync:

```
D/TAG: system time 1502071462035
D/TAG: snap DataSnapshot { key = foo, value = 1502071462001 }
D/TAG: system time 1502071463993
D/TAG: snap DataSnapshot { key = foo, value = 1502071463993 }
D/TAG: system time 1502071511215
D/TAG: snap DataSnapshot { key = foo, value = 1502071511650 }
```

The bottom line is that you should be getting client-side timestamps if you read server timestamps written while offline.

Answer (score 1):

A quick test in JavaScript:

```
var ref = firebase.database().ref("/.info/serverTimeOffset");

document.querySelector("#getOffset").addEventListener("click", function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  ref.once('value',function(snapshot) {
    var li = document.createElement("li");
    li.innerText = new Date().toString()+": "+snapshot.val();
    document.querySelector("#offsets").appendChild(li);
  });
  return false;
})
```

The output:

Go online:

> Sun Aug 06 2017 17:59:29 GMT-0700 (PDT): -3270

Go offline:

> Sun Aug 06 2017 17:59:39 GMT-0700 (PDT): -3270
>   Sun Aug 06 2017 17:59:43 GMT-0700 (PDT): -3270

Go back online:

> Sun Aug 06 2017 17:59:55 GMT-0700 (PDT): -3269

So it seems to return the cached value from the last moment it connects.

For the actual working version, see [this jsbin](https://jsbin.com/pozikol/edit?html,js,output).

Comment: thanks for the answer, it is very helpfull @Frank van Puffelen. The server timestamp is not going to be saved in the storage instead using Special location is what my app needs.

Comment: @FrankVanPuffelen, to get the approximate value of timestamp in Firestore, should I listen to `firestore.collection("/.info/serverTimeOffset")`?